# Show that $\langle v,w\rangle ^2 =\langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle$ if and only if $v$ is parallel to $w$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $ \langle.,.\rangle$ be the usual scalar product, show that $\langle v,w\rangle ^2 =\langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle$ if and only if $v$ is parallel to $w$.

this was asked after proving that every scalar product satisfies the inequality, which i managed to do.
any help on this please]

just to clarify, I'm having troubles proving the forward part, so I have proved that if $v$ is parallel to $w$ then the equality holds, just can't do the other way.

Comment: Do you know tha $<v,w>=|v||w|\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between thw two vectors?

Comment: I do know it, but I do not think we can use it yet.

Comment: Note: $<v,v>=|v|^2$ and $<w,w>=|w|^2$ and the vectors are parallel iff $\cos \theta=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically [comes from the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399391/proof-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-in-inner-product-space). You're expanding $\langle u-tw, u-tw\rangle$, and noticing that $0 \leq \langle u-tw, u-tw\rangle$, then picking a normalizing $t$ to give you the inequality. It's clear then that to get *equality* you need $u=tw$, no matter what $t$ you chose, i.e. linear dependence.

Comment: I didn't do it that proof, I could post my proof and you could tell me how my proofs induces this?

Comment: @realanalysis94: post it in the body of your question

Comment: ok ive done it now

Comment: Replace $<$ by $\leq$ and your proof of Cauchy Schwarz is fine. Now the proof of equality will follow from my answer.

Comment: I don't following your answer. "normalizing t" what does this mean? I didn't really choose $\lambda$ in my proof it was just some number

Comment: oh nevermind I see it thanks!

Comment: @realanalysis94: if you look at it's definition, $t$ (or your $\lambda$) is exactly what you need to go from $u$ to w$.